# Automation server can't create object - EXT JS Error

Tags: internet-explorer, extjs, extjs4

I am getting this error in IE 8. It says;

```
SCRIPT429: Automation server can't create object 

app.html, line 1 character 1
```

and line of of the `app.html` file is `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: I am working on a EXTJS project so, I think it's an EXT JS error. Please feel free to re-tag if you know what causes it.

Comment: If you google this error (with some answers on this site), it seems to be related to file permission. But it doesn't seem to be ExtJS related based on where the error happens. You could comment all ExtJS inclusions and see if it still happens?

Comment: did this ever get resolved?